# What is the C++ type corresponding to the QtQuick3D Node

Tags: c++, qt, qml

What is the C++ type corresponding to the [QtQuick3D Node](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick3d-camera.html)?

It is not [QNode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3dcore-qnode.html), which is a Qt3D element and not QtQuick3D. According to debugger, a QObject* pointing to a node is a QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<QQuick3DNode>, but QQuick3DNode is not a valid include so I can't instantiate it.

So if I want to have in QML `MyClass{myproperty: Node{}}`, on the C++ side it will be seen as a `Qobject*` and I can't cast it to a more precise type.

Comment: The debugger is telling you the correct class name. The fact that you don't have access to the include file does not change that. Qt may have just decided not to make that part of the public API.

Comment: So if QQuick3DNode is not part of the public API... I should instantiate them as QObject? That could lead to numerous problems, the main one I see is that I can't use the new syntax of QObject::connect and I have to use the SIGNAL() (for signals like 'rotationChanged' which are specific to Node

Comment: I faced this problem. The only solutions I found, is to use yourQObject->setProperty (and we know for a fact that yourQObject is a Quick3D::Node) Or to invoke methods of the parent of your node (QMetaObject::invokeMethod)